# Changing from PIL to PILLOW on a mac

Tags: python, macos, python-imaging-library

I'm having trouble upgrading from PIL to PILLOW on my mac. I tried "brew install libtiff lbjpeg webp littlecms" but homebrew couldn't find the lbjpeg - any tips?

Comment: Maybe because it is called "libjpeg" with an "i"?

Answer (score 2):

1. Reinstall X11 from XQuartz.org
2. Install the latest XCode
3. Install the command line tools:

   ## xcode-select --install

Worked for me on mavericks