# Installing Pillow with Mac OS X Mavericks (10.9.1)

Tags: python, macos, osx-mavericks, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to install Pillow following the instruction:

```
http://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installation.html#mac-os-x-installation
```

The issue is that I got error with `python -c 'from PIL import Image`.

```
 python -c "from PIL import Image"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 53, in <module>
    from PIL import _imaging as core
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/PIL/_imaging.so, 2): 
             Symbol not found: _jpeg_resync_to_restart
  Referenced from: /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/PIL/_imaging.so
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/PIL/_imaging.so
```

The message says `_jpeg_resync_to_restart` is not found, I googled to try solve this problem as follows:

1. Use `brew` to install `Pillow`: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-python
2. Install libjpeg and install from the source: http://www.thetoryparty.com/2010/08/31/pil-on-snow-leopard-_jpeg_resync_to_restart-error/

However, nothing works. Is there any way to install Pillow on Mavericks? I use Python 2.7: the default python interpreter.

Answer (score 7):

I confirm that following these steps I can install Pillow on Mavericks 10.9.2 with XCode 5

1:

```
brew install libtiff libjpeg webp littlecms
```

2: go to here [`https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Pillow/2.3.1`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Pillow/2.3.1) downalod the zip file and unzip it.

3: open a Terminal window and go to Pillow-2.3.1 folder in Terminal.

4: these two lines are extremely important because they will ignore the errors during installation of Pillow, without these two lines the setup cannot be finished (I am using python 2.7 so you may need to change whatever version you use):

```
sudo sed -i '' -e 's/-mno-fused-madd//g' /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/_sysconfigdata.py
sudo rm /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/_sysconfigdata.pyc
```

5: run command

```
sudo python setup.py install
```

Done!

Comment: Did you check after the compile all the tests in Tests directory of Pillow are passed?

Comment: No I haven't checked the Tests directory. But Before installation I got errors. After the installation I ran this command `python -c "from PIL import Image"` No error was shown.

Comment: by the way I am referencing [issue link](https://github.com/python-imaging/Pillow/issues/527)

Answer (score 6):

Follow these steps

1. update xcode on qppstore
2. open the terminal an type:

   1. `xcode-select --install`
   2. `su`
   3. `export CFLAGS=-Qunused-arguments`
   4. `export CPPFLAGS=-Qunused-arguments`
   5. `pip install pillow`

Comment: How about explaining what each step does and why it is needed?

Answer (score 3):

a friend told me how to fix this:

1. sudo su -
2. **export CFLAGS=-Qunused-arguments**
3. pip install Image
4. python
5. from PIL import Image

by https://github.com/moskytw

Comment: Note that this installs Django globally.

Answer (score 1):

Had this problem in Nov 2015. Easiest solution for me was to install a precompiled binary of pillow using wheels:

```
pip install wheel
pip install --use-wheel pillow
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Reinstall X11 from XQuartz.org
2. Install the latest XCode
3. Install the command line tools:

   ## xcode-select --install

Worked for me on mavericks

Comment: Exact duplicate of [your answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21503147/changing-from-pil-to-pillow-on-a-mac/22077355#22077355), stop posting duplicate answers and there by not creating redundancy.

Answer (score 0):

Installing earlier version of Pillow worked for me

```
pip uninstall pillow
pip install Pillow==2.5.0
```

Boom Ya Baby!

running MacOSX 10.8.5 `from PIL import Image` now throws no errors.