# Troubles installing pillow on Mavericks 10.9.2

Tags: installation, osx-mavericks, python-imaging-library

I've installed `command line tools`

then i installed `brew`

and last, i run the following code `brew install libtiff libjpeg webp little-cms2`

but it freezes, and in the output is showing that

[image: bash]

but i don't know where to run the `make install`

i follow the steps of one question on this [Installing Pillow with Mac OS X Mavericks (10.9.1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21867277/installing-pillow-with-mac-os-x-mavericks-10-9-1)

If now i try to install `pillow` the same thing happens, the installation screen freeze (the tab name change from xcrum to lipo all the time):

[image: pillow]

Answer (score 0):

If helps anyone this work for me

```
ARCHFLAGS=-Wno-error=unused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future pip install pillow
```