# Can't install jpeg because conflicting ports are active: libjpeg-turbo

Tags: python, ftp, macports

I am running into an issue with  libjpeg-turbo trying to install vsftpd with Mac Ports.  I'm running on OS X 10.10.5.

```
David-Laxers-MacBook-Pro:phoenix_pipeline davidlaxer$ conda -V
conda 3.16.0

David-Laxers-MacBook-Pro:phoenix_pipeline davidlaxer$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_05"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_05-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.5-b02, mixed mode)
David-Laxers-MacBook-Pro:phoenix_pipeline davidlaxer$ 

    David-Laxers-MacBook-Pro:phoenix_pipeline davidlaxer$ port -v
MacPorts 2.3.3
sudo port install vsftpd
Password:
--->  Fetching archive for vsftpd
--->  Attempting to fetch vsftpd-3.0.2_1.darwin_14.x86_64.tbz2 from http://packages.macports.org/vsftpd
--->  Attempting to fetch vsftpd-3.0.2_1.darwin_14.x86_64.tbz2.rmd160 from http://packages.macports.org/vsftpd
--->  Installing vsftpd @3.0.2_1
--->  Activating vsftpd @3.0.2_1

To configure vsftpd edit /opt/local/etc/vsftpd.conf.

--->  Cleaning vsftpd
--->  Updating database of binaries
--->  Scanning binaries for linking errors
--->  Found 99 broken file(s), matching files to ports   
--->  Found 14 broken port(s), determining rebuild order
--->  Rebuilding in order
     tiff @4.0.4 
     gd2 @2.1.1 +x11
     ghostscript @9.16 +x11
     djvulibre @3.5.27 
     webp @0.4.3 
     jasper @1.900.1 
     gdk-pixbuf2 @2.31.6 +x11
     opencv @3.0.0 
     lcms @1.19 
     libmng @1.0.10 
     netpbm @10.71.02 +x11
     lcms2 @2.7 
     ImageMagick @6.9.0-0 +x11
     poppler @0.35.0 

Error: Unable to exec port: Can't install jpeg because conflicting ports are active: libjpeg-turbo
Error rebuilding tiff
    while executing
"error "Error rebuilding $portname""
    (procedure "revupgrade_scanandrebuild" line 395)
    invoked from within
"revupgrade_scanandrebuild broken_port_counts $opts"
    (procedure "macports::revupgrade" line 5)
    invoked from within
"macports::revupgrade $opts"
    (procedure "action_revupgrade" line 2)
    invoked from within
"action_revupgrade $action $portlist $opts"
    (procedure "action_target" line 96)
    invoked from within
"$action_proc $action $portlist [array get global_options]"
    (procedure "process_cmd" line 103)
    invoked from within
"process_cmd $remaining_args"
    invoked from within
"if { [llength $remaining_args] > 0 } {

    # If there are remaining arguments, process those as a command
    set exit_status [process_cmd $remaining..."
    (file "/opt/local/bin/port" line 5268)
```

I had what could be a similar problem earlier today with python-goose:

```
David-Laxers-MacBook-Pro:python-goose davidlaxer$ anaconda search -t conda libjpg
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/users/davidlaxer/anaconda/bin/anaconda", line 6, in <module>
   sys.exit(main())
 File "/Users/davidlaxer/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/binstar_client/scripts/cli.py", line 94, in main
   description=__doc__, version=version)
 File "/Users/davidlaxer/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/binstar_client/scripts/cli.py", line 60, in binstar_main
   add_subparser_modules(parser, sub_command_module, 'conda_server.subcommand')
 File "/Users/davidlaxer/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/clyent/__init__.py", line 117, in add_subparser_modules
   for command_module in get_sub_commands(module):
 File "/Users/davidlaxer/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/clyent/__init__.py", line 106, in get_sub_commands
   this_module = __import__(module.__package__ or module.__name__, fromlist=names)
 File "/Users/davidlaxer/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/binstar_client/commands/notebook.py", line 13, in <module>
   from binstar_client.utils.notebook import Uploader, Downloader, parse, notebook_url, has_environment
 File "/Users/davidlaxer/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/binstar_client/utils/notebook/__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
   from .uploader import *
 File "/Users/davidlaxer/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/binstar_client/utils/notebook/uploader.py", line 7, in <module>
   from .data_uri import data_uri_from
 File "/Users/davidlaxer/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/binstar_client/utils/notebook/data_uri.py", line 10, in <module>
   from PIL import Image
 File "/Users/davidlaxer/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 63, in <module>
   from PIL import _imaging as core
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/davidlaxer/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PIL/_imaging.so, 2): Library not loaded: libjpeg.8.dylib
 Referenced from: /Users/davidlaxer/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PIL/_imaging.so
 Reason: Incompatible library version: _imaging.so requires version 13.0.0 or later, but libjpeg.8.dylib provides version 12.0.0
```

Continuum Analytics gave me these instructions (which resolved the 'goose' problem):

```
conda install -f pillow jpeg
I was unable to find any details of a jpeg package that has _imaging.so 13. My suggestion from here may be to reinstall goose. I did so by the following. first download the zip from https://github.com/grangier/python-goose and run the following individually.

conda create -n goose python=2.7 anaconda-client pillow lxml cssselect nltk

source activate goose

pip install -i https://pypi.anaconda.org/pypi/simple jieba

conda install -fc https://conda.anaconda.org/auto beautifulsoup4
Then move the contents of the python-goose-develop/ into the goose environment, similar to this.

cp ~/Downloads/python-goose-develop/* ~/anaconda/envs/goose

cd ~/anaconda/envs/goose

python setup.py install
```

In response to the 'answer' below from dsgfdg.

```
David-Laxers-MacBook-Pro:phoenix_pipeline davidlaxer$ sudo !!
sudo port install webp
--->  Computing dependencies for webp
Error: Unable to execute port: Can't install jpeg because conflicting ports are active: libjpeg-turbo
```

I downloaded Pillow 2.3.1 and built it.
It build successfully but then fails the tests.  Here's an excerpt.

```
David-Laxers-MacBook-Pro:Pillow-2.3.1 davidlaxer$ python Tests/run.py
--------------------------------------------------------------------
running test_000_sanity ...
=== error 256
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Tests/test_000_sanity.py", line 5, in <module>
    import PIL.Image
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.5-x86_64/egg/PIL/Image.py", line 53, in <module>
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.5-x86_64/egg/PIL/_imaging.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.5-x86_64/egg/PIL/_imaging.py", line 6, in __bootstrap__
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/davidlaxer/.python-eggs/Pillow-2.3.1-py2.7-macosx-10.5-x86_64.egg-tmp/PIL/_imaging.so, 2): Library not loaded: libjpeg.8.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/davidlaxer/.python-eggs/Pillow-2.3.1-py2.7-macosx-10.5-x86_64.egg-tmp/PIL/_imaging.so
  Reason: Incompatible library version: _imaging.so requires version 13.0.0 or later, but libjpeg.8.dylib provides version 12.0.0
running test_001_archive ...
=== error 256
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Tests/test_001_archive.py", line 2, in <module>
    import PIL.Image
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.5-x86_64/egg/PIL/Image.py", line 53, in <module>
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.5-x86_64/egg/PIL/_imaging.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.5-x86_64/egg/PIL/_imaging.py", line 6, in __bootstrap__
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/davidlaxer/.python-eggs/Pillow-2.3.1-py2.7-macosx-10.5-x86_64.egg-tmp/PIL/_imaging.so, 2): Library not loaded: libjpeg.8.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/davidlaxer/.python-eggs/Pillow-2.3.1-py2.7-macosx-10.5-x86_64.egg-tmp/PIL/_imaging.so
  Reason: Incompatible library version: _imaging.so requires version 13.0.0 or later, but libjpeg.8.dylib provides version 12.0.0
running test_file_bmp ...
=== error 256
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Tests/test_file_bmp.py", line 3, in <module>
    from PIL import Image
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.5-x86_64/egg/PIL/Image.py", line 53, in <module>
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.5-x86_64/egg/PIL/_imaging.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.5-x86_64/egg/PIL/_imaging.py", line 6, in __bootstrap__
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/davidlaxer/.python-eggs/Pillow-2.3.1-py2.7-macosx-10.5-x86_64.egg-tmp/PIL/_imaging.so, 2): Library not loaded: libjpeg.8.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/davidlaxer/.python-eggs/Pillow-2.3.1-py2.7-macosx-10.5-x86_64.egg-tmp/PIL/_imaging.so
  Reason: Incompatible library version: _imaging.so requires version 13.0.0 or later, but libjpeg.8.dylib provides version 12.0.0
running test_file_eps ...
=== error 256
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Tests/test_file_eps.py", line 3, in <module>
    from PIL import Image, EpsImagePlugin
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.5-x86_64/egg/PIL/Image.py", line 53, in <module>
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.5-x86_64/egg/PIL/_imaging.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.5-x86_64/egg/PIL/_imaging.py", line 6, in __bootstrap__
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/davidlaxer/.python-eggs/Pillow-2.3.1-py2.7-macosx-10.5-x86_64.egg-tmp/PIL/_imaging.so, 2): Library not loaded: libjpeg.8.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/davidlaxer/.python-eggs/Pillow-2.3.1-py2.7-macosx-10.5-x86_64.egg-tmp/PIL/_imaging.so
  Reason: Incompatible library version: _imaging.so requires version 13.0.0 or later, but libjpeg.8.dylib provides version 12.0.0
running test_file_fli ...
=== error 256
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Tests/test_file_fli.py", line 3, in <module>
    from PIL import Image
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.5-x86_64/egg/PIL/Image.py", line 53, in <module>
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.5-x86_64/egg/PIL/_imaging.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.5-x86_64/egg/PIL/_imaging.py", line 6, in __bootstrap__
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/davidlaxer/.python-eggs/Pillow-2.3.1-py2.7-macosx-10.5-x86_64.egg-tmp/PIL/_imaging.so, 2): Library not loaded: libjpeg.8.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/davidlaxer/.python-eggs/Pillow-2.3.1-py2.7-macosx-10.5-x86_64.egg-tmp/PIL/_imaging.so
  Reason: Incompatible library version: _imaging.so requires version 13.0.0 or later, but libjpeg.8.dylib provides version 12.0.0
running test_file_gif ...
=== error 256
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Tests/test_file_gif.py", line 3, in <module>
    from PIL import Image
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.5-x86_64/egg/PIL/Image.py", line 53, in <module>
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.5-x86_64/egg/PIL/_imaging.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.5-x86_64/egg/PIL/_imaging.py", line 6, in __bootstrap__
```

...

ImportError: dlopen(/Users/davidlaxer/.python-eggs/Pillow-2.3.1-py2.7-macosx-10.5-x86_64.egg-tmp/PIL/_imaging.so, 2): Library not loaded: libjpeg.8.dylib
      Referenced from: /Users/davidlaxer/.python-eggs/Pillow-2.3.1-py2.7-macosx-10.5-x86_64.egg-tmp/PIL/_imaging.so
      Reason: Incompatible library version: _imaging.so requires version 13.0.0 or later, but libjpeg.8.dylib provides version 12.0.0
    --------------------------------------------------------------------
    *** 94 tests of 94 failed.
    David-Laxers-MacBook-Pro:Pillow-2.3.1 davidlaxer$

```
David-Laxers-MacBook-Pro:scraper davidlaxer$ python scraper.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "scraper.py", line 8, in <module>
    from goose import Goose
  File "/users/davidlaxer/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/goose/__init__.py", line 27, in <module>
    from goose.crawler import CrawlCandidate
  File "/users/davidlaxer/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/goose/crawler.py", line 31, in <module>
    from goose.images.extractors import UpgradedImageIExtractor
  File "/users/davidlaxer/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/goose/images/extractors.py", line 28, in <module>
    from goose.images.utils import ImageUtils
  File "/users/davidlaxer/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/goose/images/utils.py", line 26, in <module>
    from PIL import Image
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.5-x86_64/egg/PIL/Image.py", line 53, in <module>
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.5-x86_64/egg/PIL/_imaging.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.5-x86_64/egg/PIL/_imaging.py", line 6, in __bootstrap__
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/davidlaxer/.python-eggs/Pillow-2.3.1-py2.7-macosx-10.5-x86_64.egg-tmp/PIL/_imaging.so, 2): Library not loaded: libjpeg.8.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/davidlaxer/.python-eggs/Pillow-2.3.1-py2.7-macosx-10.5-x86_64.egg-tmp/PIL/_imaging.so
  Reason: Incompatible library version: _imaging.so requires version 13.0.0 or later, but libjpeg.8.dylib provides version 12.0.0
```

Comment: answered here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21867277/installing-pillow-with-mac-os-x-mavericks-10-9-1

Comment: dsgdfg's link (in answer) broke other programs (see edit's in post above).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that both the `libjpeg-turbo` and the `jpeg` port in MacPorts provide `libjpeg.dylib` and corresponding headers (consequently, they conflict with each other and cannot be installed simultaneously), but the `jpeg` port ships `libjpeg.9.dylib`, which is ABI-incompatible with `libjpeg-turbo`'s `libjpeg.8.dylib`.

The problem is not caused by the installation of the `vsftpd` port; rather, MacPorts runs a sanity check after each installation or update called `rev-upgrade` that checks for ABI compatibility issues such as referencing non-existant or incompatible libraries. When it detects such issues (as in your case), it attempts to rebuild the broken ports to fix the issues.

This sanity checks determines that your `tiff` port is broken, because one of its binaries or libraries links against `libjpeg.9.dylib` -- this file doesn't exist because it is provided by the `jpeg` port, but you only have `libjpeg-turbo` installed. The rebuild then attempts to install the `jpeg` port as a dependency of `tiff` and fails because of the conflict.

You have multiple options at this point:

- Uninstall `libjpeg-turbo` and install `jpeg`. That should fix your issues, but is only an option if you don't explicitly want `libjpeg-turbo` for some reason.
- Uninstall all ports that explicitly depend on the `jpeg` port and rebuild those that will accept `libjpeg-turbo` as a provider of the `libjpeg.dylib` library; unfortunately, the `tiff` port is currently not among them:

  ```
  $> port info --depends_lib tiff
  depends_lib: port:jpeg, port:xz, port:zlib
  ```

  This would contain `path:lib/libjpeg.dylib:jpeg` if it supported both versions. A quick survey suggests only very few ports in MacPorts currently support `libjpeg-turbo` to provide JPEG functionality. This may change in the future (and in fact, there was a discussion about that recently on the mailing lists).

**TL;DR:**

```
sudo port -f uninstall libjpeg-turbo
sudo port install jpeg
sudo port rev-upgrade
```

Comment: So far, no issues.  Thank You!